# Why does this ThreadPoolExecutor execute futures way before they are called?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Why does this `ThreadPoolExecutor` execute `futures` way before they are called?

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time

def sleep_test(order_number):
    num_seconds = 0.5
    print(f"Order {order_number} - Sleeping {num_seconds} seconds")
    time.sleep(num_seconds)
    print(f"Order {order_number} - Slept {num_seconds} seconds")
    if order_number == 4:
        raise Exception("Reached order #4")

def main():
    order_numbers = [i for i in range(10_000)]
    max_number_of_threads = 2

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_number_of_threads) as executor:
        futures = []
        for order in order_numbers:
            futures.append(executor.submit(sleep_test, order_number=order))

        for future in futures:
            if future.cancelled():
                continue
            try:
                _ = future.result()
            except Exception:
                print("Caught Exception, stopping all future orders")
                executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is a sample execution:

```
$ python3 thread_pool_test.py
Order 0 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 1 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 0 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 1 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 2 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 3 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 2 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 4 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 3 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 5 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 4 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 6 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Caught Exception, stopping all future orders
Order 5 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 4706 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 6 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 4706 - Slept 0.5 seconds
```

All of a sudden Order 4706 is called seemingly out of nowhere which doesn't make sense to me. I expect the threads to stop at around Order 5 or 6 which is when the `Exception` is hit. Sometimes when I run the script it works as expected but other times it calls a function that is thousands of "futures" in the future.

Why is this happening? Can I stop this from happening?

Comment: This behavior seems very peculiar. I tried giving smaller ranges, like 100 or 1000, and it is less frequent. It is getting more frequent when giving larger and larger range. Also, the order which is called is in the thousands, but it is quite random, not a particular number.

Comment: I've tried this with varying values for the main loop and number of threads and am unable to replicate on macOS with Python 3.11.4

Comment: @DarkKnight Did you try exceptionally large numbers? If I try with 100_000 it happens every time

Comment: @JoshCorreia You are right. I tried with 100_000 and also observe this behaviour. This is very strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer:

It appears that `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown` has no mechanism to prevent this, based on the CPython implementation.

It is difficult to completely avoid this, but if you have a list of futures, you can at least avoid having them executed out of order by canceling them manually in reverse order as below.

```py
for f in futures[::-1]:  # The key is to cancel in reverse order.
    f.cancel()
```

### In Detail:

First, let's look at the `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit` [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L161).

The following is a **simplified** version (See the above link for the actual code).
When you submit `fn`, it is wrapped in `_WorkItem` and put into the queue.

```py
def submit(self, fn, /, *args, **kwargs):
    f = _base.Future()
    w = _WorkItem(f, fn, args, kwargs)
    self._work_queue.put(w)
    return f
```

The [worker thread](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L69) takes this out and runs it.

```py
def _worker(executor_reference, work_queue, initializer, initargs):
    while True:
        work_item = work_queue.get(block=True)
        if work_item is not None:
            work_item.run()
```

Note that the worker thread is not locking anything during this operation.

Instead, the `_WorkItem` [checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L53) the status of the future before executing the `fn`.
If the future is canceled, execution will be aborted here.

```py
def run(self):
    if not self.future.set_running_or_notify_cancel():
        return
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

Finally, here is the shutdown [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L216).

```py
def shutdown(self, wait=True, *, cancel_futures=False):
    if cancel_futures:
        while True:
            try:
                work_item = self._work_queue.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                break
            if work_item is not None:
                work_item.future.cancel()
```

It takes all items from the queue and cancels them sequentially.
Note that it locks something called `self._shutdown_lock`, but this lock does not affect the worker because the worker side does not lock anything.

Taken together, if the thread that executed the `shutdown` (in this case, the main thread) releases the GIL for some reason in the middle of emptying the queue, the worker thread can retrieve the item in the middle.
And since future is only cancelled when `shutdown` retrieves it, it will be executed if a worker thread retrieves it.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation and a solution to the problem. Cancelling the futures in reverse order seems to have done the trick. I even tried with 1_000_000 orders and it still works! For anyone reading this in the future, I replaced the `executor.shutdown()` line with this and it works great.

Answer (score 4):

You already got a good answer (thanks, @ken!), but since I typed this up before I'll post it now anyway.

There's generally no answer to questions like this short of staring at the implementation. Did anything in the docs promise that things would work here the way you expected? If not, you're at the mercy of the implementation.

In general, *nothing* about multi-thread or multi-process behavior is "synchronized" as you might expect it to be, unless the docs promise it, or you force it with your own machinery.

In this case, an `Executor` object maintains a queue of work items to be executed, and the code that passes those items out for execution runs in a different thread than `Executor.shutdown()` runs in (that runs in the thread you called it from, which in your test case is the program's main thread). The threads in the thread pool *also* extract work items from that queue.

So there's ample opportunity for race conditions under the covers, as multiple threads contend over who gets to extract the next item from the queue of pending work items. Look at the source code in `Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py`, method `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()`. The relevant part loops over the queue one at a time until the queue is empty:

```py
while True:
    try:
        work_item = self._work_queue.get_nowait()
    except queue.Empty:
        break
    if work_item is not None:
        work_item.future.cancel()
```

But otherwise-idle worker threads in the pool are also looping over the queue simultaneously, looking for new work items to work on. "Who wins" isn't defined, or predictable.

In your test program, the worker threads are sleeping long enough that it's likely that the shutdown loop can consume the entire queue before a worker thread wakes up again and comes back to look for more work to do.  But there's no guarantee of that. And the more items on the queue, the more likely a worker *will* wake up and grab another work item before `shutdown()` consumes the entire queue.

For example, on my box just now, boosting the number of work items to a million:

```
Order 0 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 1 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 0 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 1 - Slept 0.5 seconds
...
Order 36 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 35 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 37 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Caught Exception, stopping all future orders
Order 36 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 331479 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 37 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 382046 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 331479 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 792063 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 382046 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 837591 - Sleeping 0.5 seconds
Order 792063 - Slept 0.5 seconds
Order 837591 - Slept 0.5 seconds
```

The queue was so large in this case that worker threads woke up and grabbed new items multiple times while `shutdown()` was working on draining the queue.

You can't stop this, but you should learn to live with it ;-) In a parallel world, calling `.submit()` just says you want an item to be executed *sometime*. You shouldn't assume anything about when it will be executed (for example, you shouldn't even assume that items passed to `.submit()` before will be executed before the new item - there's no guarantee of that either), or that it will be possible to cancel it before it runs. Any kind of synchronized, deterministic behavior you may want needs to be forced with appropriate extra app-specific synchronization code (locks, queues, semaphores, events, condition variables, ...).

Comment: Thank you Tim, that makes a lot of sense. I think my best bet to avoid this is to have a smaller number of items, maybe I can try using `executor.map()`'s chunk size.